# Send HTTP request from different IPs in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, tor, http-request

Is there a way to send an HTTP request with a different IP from what I have in Node.js?

I want to send a request from an IP that I choose before, and not from the IP of the server or from my computer’s IP.

I know that Tor Project does this kind of manipulation, but I didn't find any library that Tor uses to do this stuff.

Is there any API or Node.js module that Tor uses to handle this kind of private browsing in Node.js?

Comment: Answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/70807964/82686

Answer (score 23):

In the node http module there is a [localAddress](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) option for binding to specific network interface.

```
var http = require('http');

var options = {
  hostname: 'www.example.com',
  localAddress: '202.1.1.1'
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log(chunk.toString());
  });
});
```

Check out [Mikeal's Request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) on Github.

Tor uses SOCKS5 and these two modules can help: [socks5-http-client](https://github.com/mattcg/socks5-http-client) and [socks5-https-client](https://github.com/mattcg/socks5-https-client)

```
require('socks5-http-client').request(options, function(res) {
  console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
  console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
  });
});
```

Another option is to use a free web proxy, such as the Hide My Ass [web proxy](http://www.hidemyass.com/proxy/). They also provide a list of [ip:port proxies](http://www.hidemyass.com/proxy-list/) which you can use. Both http, https and even SOCKS4/5. Either use the above modules or simply configure your web browser to use one of them.

You could even setup your own private http proxy node app and deploy on Heroku. I found a ton of easy to follow examples on Google.

Comment: Note that this only allows you to send requests from IP addresses that are configured on your machine. You can't just use any old address!

Comment: Yes yes, this example is for when your server has multiple IPs and you want to pick and choose.

Comment: I've added a few more examples

Comment: Has this been helpful?

Comment: @MikeCauser do you have any example about how to use HideMyAss with `request`?:)