# Send request from different source ip address

Tags: node.js, http, request, xmpp

I want to send xmpp request with `node-xmpp` library from different source IP address in my node.js project.
I have 6 IP and i can get my IP with `os.networkInterfaces();`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send HTTP request from different IPs in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20294190/send-http-request-from-different-ips-in-node-js)

Comment: I can not change IP address with `LocalAddress`

Comment: What is your current code for making an xmpp request without assigning the source IP address?